# Is there a more DRY way to dynamically add a class depending on route in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a navbar that includes the following elements:

```
%li 
  = link_to 'About', 'about'
%li
  = link_to 'Help', 'help'
%li 
  = link_to 'FAQ', 'faq'
```

When someone visits the specific page, I'd like to add the class `active` to the `li` depending on which page is visited. For example, if they visited the FAQ page, the end result would look like:

```
%li 
  = link_to 'About', 'about'
%li
  = link_to 'Help', 'help'
%li.active
  = link_to 'FAQ', 'faq'
```

Here is what I'm currently using:

```
- if request.env['PATH_INFO'] == '/about'
  %li.active
    = link_to 'About', 'about'
- else
  %li
    = link_to 'About', 'about'

- if request.env['PATH_INFO'] == '/help'
  %li.active
    = link_to 'Help', 'help'
- else
  %li
    = link_to 'Help', 'help'

- if request.env['PATH_INFO'] == '/faq'
  %li.active
    = link_to 'FAQ', 'faq'
- else
  %li
    = link_to 'FAQ', 'faq'
```

Is there a way to do this that requires less repetition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [link_to_unless_current](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_unless_current) (and the variations of [url_helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html)) in the API docs.

To get the `li.active`, can you use [current_page?](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3F). Something like:

```
%li{class:("active" if current_page?)}
  %= link_to_unless_current "Help", "help"
```

To have a link always present, whether on the current page or not, then it's simply:

```
%li{class:("active" if current_page?)}
  %= link_to "Help", "help"
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that if I pass in a `class` argument, it will add the class to the `<a>` tag, not the `<li>` tag that's wrapping it. I'd be able to get the same results as `%a.active`, but not `%li.active`.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. Apologies, I was moving too fast. Let me look at it again. Sorry.

Comment: While I'm looking, another thought. If you are using the `.active` class for styling, would you be able to style the `a` tag instead of the `li` tag?

Comment: I'm using [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/) as my CSS framework, so I guess I could edit the code to allow me to add the `.active` class to `a` tags as well, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Your edited comment works well with some modifications. Small syntax error, though. You apparently need parenthesis around the condition, as well as some parameters for the `current_page?` call. My final solution: `%li{class: ('active' if current_page?('/faq'))}` and then `=link_to 'FAQ', 'faq'` on the second line. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad I was able to help. With your solution, you'll always end up with a link (whether on the current page or not). Is that true? Often, I don't want an link if on the current page, but I suppose that's a matter of preference.

Comment: yes, that is correct. I'm okay with having the link there still. The odds of the user clicking that link are small and if they do, the page will just refresh and that's not a huge deal in this current application.

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://github.com/comfy/active_link_to gem for this. It is very simple yet customizeable. It will add `active` class if it matches some route(matching can be customized)

```
active_link_to 'Users', '/users'
# => <a href="/users" class="active">Users</a>
```

or

```
active_link_to 'Users', users_path, :wrap_tag => :li
# => <li class="active"><a href="/users" class="active">Users</a></li>
```

Comment: I really enjoy the `wrap_tag` parameter, but the other solution doesn't require a gem to be installed. Will definitely keep this in mind though, thanks for sharing!